# Explicitly set user schema in Bookshelf for PG

Tags: postgresql, connection-string, bookshelf.js, knex.js

In our dev environment, each dev has their own schema to replicate the stage and prod databases. Need to be able to pass user schema as part of the client config. Here's the config...

```
"client": {
    "username":       "user_login",
    "password":       "user_password",
    "host":           "db_host",
    "port":           5432,
    "database":       "db_name",
    "dialect":        "pg",
    "schema":         "user_schema"
}
```

...and here's the instantiation...

```
var Knex = require('knex')({
             client: client.dialect,
             connection: {
                host: client.host,
                user: client.username,
                password: client.password,
                database: client.database,
                searchPath: client.schema
           });
var Bookshelf = require('bookshelf')(Knex);
```

Inspecting the Bookshelf and Knex objects, I can't determine anywhere which schema is being used. I had to dig into the SchemaCompiler_PG.prototype.hasTable method, where I happened to find it in an array on a query response object, which includes a property of table_schema, happily set to public. I tried to set it to my schema, but nothing succeeded.

So we set default search paths for each user login.

```
ALTER ROLE user_login SET search_path TO 'user_schema'
```

Inspecting the response object, table_schema was set to my search path. But when another dev tried to run the code on her machine (local instances of Node and PG), that response object was set to MY schema. We can find no way to manually set it.

No idea what kind of black magic that would be, but need to know how to set the user schema for Bookshelf/Knex/PG.

Comment: Please be more specific on what "acts even more strangely" means. And what exactly does "attaches to public schema" mean? A connection isn't "attached" to a schema. There is also no error message in Postgres that says "No worky"  - and I'm pretty sure there isn't one in Knex or Bookshelf either (although I have no idea what those libraries actually do). And what exactly is "running on a another dev machine" mean? Does the database run on a different machine? Is the application that uses that login running on a different machine?

Comment: Corrected for clarity.  I'll add a pull request for a 'No Worky' error in Knex later.  (Kidding....)

Comment: This looks more like a problem in those libraries. Does the search path work correctly when you query the database through plain SQL (e.g. in psql or any other SQL client)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I haven't been able to find an answer for the original question, how to set the PG schema, I was able to resolve the issue at hand. Turned out to be a permissions issue in PG. Ensure that all users had r/w perms in their respective search_path and all was well.

No error messages that I could find anywhere within Bookshelf, Knex or PG client pointed to this as a possible culprit, so hopefully this helps somebody.